# Unable to determine right mime-type on Linux

Tags: linux, mime-types

I'm using [mime-util-2.1.3](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) to check mime types a file. I have noticed that on linux it is unable to correctly detect flv files. The mime type is shown as application/octet-stream, while on windows the mime type is correctly determined as video/x-flv. mp4 videos were detected though. How do I make the application to recognize the flv mime type on Linux ?

Comment: can you post the command and output of your failed attempt?

Comment: MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector");
 
File f = new File(args[0]);
Collection<?> mimeTypes = MimeUtil.getMimeTypes(f);
System.out.println(mimeTypes);

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on linux. It is detecting some plain text files like .txt, MANIFEST.MF (a text file), and .jsp as [application/octet-stream]. On linux, if I run from a command line "file -i" or "mimetype -M" on these same files I get the correct mimetypes.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing with this:`MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.MagicMimeMimeDetector"); MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.ExtensionMimeDetector");
MimeUtil.registerMimeDetector("eu.medsea.mimeutil.detector.OpendesktopMimeDetector");`

I was only registering the first one, MagicMimeMimeDetector. Once I added in the other two, it all started working correctly.

Comment: Just a quick followup, I just tested this against a flv file and got mimetype of video/x-flv, so that should do the trick for you